# Display related products using a shortcode on WooCommerce My account Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

I'm trying to display related products in My account Dashboard page. I followed this [WooCommerce Shortcodes documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-17).

I tried to use the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'output_shortcode_on_child_pages');
function output_shortcode_on_child_pages() {
    $post = get_post();
    
    if ( is_page() AND $post->post_parent ) {
        echo do_shortcode( '[related_products limit=”3″]' );
    }
}
```

This does not display the related products. But when I try to display products in specific category like following, it works:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'output_shortcode_on_child_pages');
function output_shortcode_on_child_pages() {
    $post = get_post();
    
    if ( is_page() AND $post->post_parent ) {
        echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="3" columns="3" orderby="rand" category=”presets-and-actions” ]' );
    }  
}
```

Kindly any help to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that related products shortcode **need to be used on single product pages**, as related products are always linked to a product, that's why `[related_products limit="3"]` shortcode doesn't work on My account dashboard.

Now to target my account dashboard, replace in your function this code lines:

```
$post = get_post();

if ( is_page() AND $post->post_parent ) {
```

by this unique code line:

```
if ( is_account_page() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
```

It's much better. See [WooCommerce Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-10)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @loictheaztec . Is there any other method to display related products here ? without shortcode. Any idea where i can start?

Comment: is it possible to show it related to last order by user ?

Comment: @teqqq Do you mean to Get related products based on the products purchased in the last order for the current user? Yes it should be possible… Please ask a new question: ""show related products based from last purchases on WooCommerce My account dashboard". Add in your question your code updated with explanations. Once published, notify me here with the link of your new question.